# Are barcodes symmetric?

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

This is just a confirmation. Are barcodes symmetric.
By symmetric I mean, if I rotate the barcode by 180 degrees. Will it have the same data decoded.
Basically does angle matter while scanning barcode? And are there any exceptions in the type of barcode.

Comment: A LOT of information is in the wikpedia article... care to have a look? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the barcodes themselves are generally not symmetrical (I'll clarify that - you *may* be able to find one that is symmetrical but the vast majority of the standard ones are not).

However, any *decent* reader (such as the ones at your local supermarket) will scan in a large number of different directions to take care of this, not just backwards and forwards but at other angles as well. So you can generally rotate them to your heart's content.

Even the ones that scan in a line (such as some hand-held units) may scan both directions - it depends on what you've paid for. Of course, if you have a "Dodgy Brothers" brand reader, you'll probably find it *won't* do that.

Some barcode standards will allow for detecting upside down barcodes. For example UPCA swaps black and white on the right hand side so that readers can adjust for it.

Comment: So basically you mean that a barcode oriented at 0deg or 180 deg should show different value? (assuming purely on the basis of value it holds and not the skill of detector)

Comment: I don't understand why you would ask a question if you weren't inclined to read the answers you are given.

Answer (score 1):

Usually there is a start code and a check code in each bar code so the angle doesn't matter.